# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields Img Src(Unknown)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field titled "Row" where I have an image and text.

I've literally copied the same code from a past theme, but for some reason, the image is not displaying properly in my new one. Here is a snippet of my code in page.php:

```
$aboutPagePosts = new WP_Query(array(
    'Posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'row',
    'category_name' => 'about'));

$image = get_field('image');

?>

<div class="page-section container">
<?php 
    while($aboutPagePosts->have_posts()) {
        $aboutPagePosts->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php echo $pageTitle ?></h2>
        <div class="left-image-row">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" alt="">
            <div class="section-text">
                <?php the_field('text'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The page is displaying the row since I see the field text where it should be. However, when I inspect the page, I see `img src(unknown)` in the html.

Anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: should the custom field image come from a post in the custom query?

Comment: @mikerojas yes. Within my field group "row" I have two fields - image and text.   There are three rows tagged as "about" for the about page... all three are getting displayed onto the correct page, but all three images have src unknown.

Comment: I posted a possible fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you may need to move the image call  to inside your `while` loop like below:

```
$aboutPagePosts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'row',
    'category_name' => 'about'
));

?>

<div class="page-section container">
    <?php while($aboutPagePosts->have_posts()) : $aboutPagePosts->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php echo $pageTitle ?></h2>
        <div class="left-image-row">

            <?php $image = get_field('image'); ?>

            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="">
            <div class="section-text">
                <?php the_field('text'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); /* make sure to reset post data */ ?>
</div>
```

Also `Posts_per_page` should be all lowercase `posts_per_page`.

Comment: This code comes with errors, but for anyone experiencing the same issue <?php echo $image['url'] ?> should be changed to <?php echo $image ?> within this example.

Comment: Updated answer per @MadisonLeopold comment above.